# configure jasmine to not run tests randomly

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular7

i just upgraded to jasmine 3.3 and now my tests by default run in random order. Is there a way to configure karma and jasmine to make tests run like they used to before upgrading to this new version?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Karma config under client: you are supposed to be able to set jasmine:{random:false} but that does not work for me. Does it for you?
See below link from docs and screen cap.
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I've been searching for clear documentation about this, but it was not easily found. Thanks for posting. I'm running 4.1 of karma and 3.4 of jasmine.

Comment: Worked for me as well on *Karma 4.4.1* and *Jasmine 3.5.4*. Thanks!

Comment: adding just jasmine: {random: false} was enough to set the default to running the tests in order. thanks for the structure! :)

Comment: It works for me,  "jasmine: {random: false}" definition is enough for karma config

Comment: It works, thanks. Should be marked as correct I suppose.  "karma": "5.2.3", "jasmine-core": "3.5.0"

Comment: it's working for me as well, but one doubt  => random:false is advisable ?  please provide ur expert comment

Comment: This is documented in Jasmine configuration https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html#random

Answer (score 4):

A well-written unit test case should provide the same result independent of its execution order.
However, We can change the execution order of Jasmine

Example 1- Add command line flag if you are just using Jasmine

```
jasmine test/sample.test.js  --random=false //global installation 
npx jasmine test/sample.test.js  --random=false //local installation
```

Example 2- with karma add this to your config object.

```
 module.exports = function (config) {
   config.set({
    client:{
      jasmine:{
       random:false
     }
   },
  // rest of karma configuration goes here 
  
};
```

//tested with  karma 6.3.4 and jasmine v3.8.0

Comment: You're not wrong, but a _failing_ unit test from uncontrolled side effects between tests is often much easier to _debug_ when you can disable the randomness. `;^)`