# Can I run Karma Tests with a specified seed?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm working in an Angular Project that is tested with Karma/Jasmine.
Angular tests, by default, run in a randomized order, which may result a test failing if ran in a certain order.

I've noticed that in my browser runner, it displays the randomized seed that the tests were ran with.
When running tests, can I specify this seed, so that I can test the same order more than once? (And so I can pass this seed to others to show in what order their tests fail).

Comment: This question seems very clear and detailed to me, so much so that when I read it I find myself saying "Yes, that is exactly my problem, and exactly my question", and personally I'm not sure why it has been marked as lacking detail or clarity.

I think it should be reopened, not least because the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question about how to specify a seed. Fortunately, this blog post does: https://dev.to/mistomin/flaky-unit-tests-in-angular-21n6

Maybe someone with enough reputation could vote to reopen?

Comment: @TimHirst I agree, I just don't have the rep to reopen it :( (I really don't know how it's unclear at all)

Comment: @TimHirst This has been reopened! If you post your comment as a solution, it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mikhail Istomin's blog post [here](https://dev.to/mistomin/flaky-unit-tests-in-angular-21n6) points out (under the section titled "The Seed") you can take the seed value that failed and add it to the jasmine section of your `karma.config.js` file like this:

```
// karma.config.js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // ... other settings
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: true,
        seed: '05217'
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `random` to false in karma config to always get the same order in Jasmine 3.x.

[configure jasmine to not run tests randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086722/configure-jasmine-to-not-run-tests-randomly)

In order for the seed, there is a seed option as well but I am not sure in how to use it. It says it is a function but I see '4321' provided in the second link.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

Either way, I think specifying `random: false` should be enough for you because this should be the same order on each run.