# Karma - Run slow tests in the end

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a test suite for Angular using Jasmine and Karma with 100 tests, where 1 of them, predictably and reasonably takes 95% of the time of the entire suite.

Is there a way to make that test always run at the end?

The reasoning is that when I work on another component, I won't like to wait for this test to run.

Alternatively, is there a way to, in the test command just skip the test with that name? (so I'll have two commands, one with and one without it)

Answer (score 0):

you can `xdescribe` some tests so they won't be executed, and the things that in your case is even better - you can `fdescribe` tests to ONLY run tests for your component.

but really, if one test takes so long, you should optimise this test

Comment: To add to this, you can also specify the seed for `Jasmine` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432941/7365461. Maybe you can play around with the seed to always run those tests at the end. But I think the tests running in a random order is a good feature so you know they don't rely on the order they are executed and that they are independent.