# angular "ng test" fixed tests order

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

My angular app was newly created with "ng new" using @angular/cli@16.2.0 and I started adding a tests.spec.ts in which I need the tests to run in order. How to do this properly in today's angular?

My google research led me to the latest info [configure jasmine to not run tests randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086722/configure-jasmine-to-not-run-tests-randomly) which is unfortunately 2 years old and from which my attempt to add the following karma.config.js to my project did not help:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random:false
      }
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/app/*.spec.ts'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser instances should be started simultaneously
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Comment: Why do you need your tests to run in a particular order.  This is usually not a good idea.  Your tests should be able to be run in any order and should be able to be run individually as well.

Comment: https://qualitycoding.org/random-test-order/

Comment: @JakeSmith Yes, I am aware of the necessity of random tests and what I actually wanted to achieve is having random=false only for tests within certain specs and not globally. And what I am being stucked at is making angular respects karma/jasmine configuration files or alternatives.

Comment: I have had issues in the past with karma/jasmine configuration taking effect too.  Not sure how to solve that or what that is the case sometimes.  However, if you really want to control the order of some of the tests, maybe you can just create a separate npm script in your package.json that runs each of the spec files, one after another, in the order you desire.  But your main npm test script will still try to run all the spec files in the project unless you tell it to ignore a particular folder or something like that.